# run npm install (VueJs and dependencies) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

I installed a fresh Laravel in my system, removed all nodejs and npm package and folders and reinstalled the latest version. I did all but so far I cant run the npm install and npm run dev too. Can you help me?

Follow package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

Follow print screen errors and images:

[When run: npm install](https://ibb.co/iFjtnn)

[..continue npm install](https://ibb.co/bRwZtS)

[When run: npm run dev](https://ibb.co/cmOQ07)

Comment: I agree it seems like a permission problem. Did you clone  using a regular user?

Comment: I used chmod 777 -R to folder 'zero' and used sudo npm install but happened the same way

Comment: You shouldn't sudo package managers. That's just asking for trouble. Most will warn you.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your permissions with this command in the terminal

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/zero 
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/zero/storage
```

Comment: chgrp: cannot access 'chmod': No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot access '775': No such file or directory

Comment: Ok sorry. Then run them separately

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, cross-env must have updated its paths, it has "cross-env/dist/bin" not "cross-env/bin/" in package.json. Thanks for help!!!!